# Passing a variable to a function and modifying it

Tags: c

I have a variable in a function and want to pass to another recursive function and modify it. I keep getting errors.

```
void interleave(CardDeck  *leftDeck, CardDeck  *rightDeck)
{
    int leftindex = 0;
    int rightindex = 0;
}

void poker(CardDeck *leftDeck, CardDeck *rightDeck, CardDeck * deck, int *leftindex, int *rightindex)
{
    *leftindex++;   //want to increase the value by one when needed. it will be used in  various calculations.  
}
```

`CardDeck` are structures, and that code works. The main issues I am having is that the local variables as I discovered keep getting reset to 0 on the recursive calls of poker. I needed a variable that will stay the same. I want to use `leftindex` for array, i.e. `leftdeck->cards[leftindex]`.

Comment: Your code is missing lots of stuff - like what is `CardDeck` and where/how do you call the functions you have shown?

Comment: consider `(*leftindex)++`... order of operations matter. If you don't remember a correct order, use parentheses.

Comment: So, you're getting errors?  Why don't you tell us exactly what those errors are?

Comment: If `*leftindex++;` is not a typo, the problem is not that they're getting reset but that they're never modified. You can make this bug less likely by using `+= 1` instead of `++`.

Comment: You can use global variable . How you passing the variable in recursive call is important . Check that also .